# Why isn't this jQuery script working?

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr.reqDet").hide(); 

  $("[title='requestType']").change(function(){
    if ($("[title='requestType']").val()!=""){
        $("#reqDet").hide();
    } else {  
        $("#reqDet").show();  
    }
  });

</script>
```

I cannot get the if statement in the script to work...

Details: I'm using SharePoint and it renders a dropdown box w/ attribute title="requestType". When the requestType box is NOT set to the initial value, which is "", I'd like for a control with the class "reqDet" to appear.

---

Anyways, Thanks everyone. here's the solution that worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr.reqDet").hide(); 

  $("select[title='requestType']").change(function(){
        $(".reqDet").toggle($(this).val()!== "");
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: "Cannot get it to work" how exactly?

Comment: Can you show the markup at all?

Comment: What kind of an element is the dropdown box (that has the `requestType` title)?

Comment: Have you used Firebug to see how many elements match your selector of $("[title='requestType']")? And if so, you may want to change that code to $(this).val()!="" instead of $("[title='requestType']").val()!=""

Comment: please include html code too.

Answer (score 5):

**Updated answer:** Since you mention "the element with the class `reqDet`", the problem would be that you are using an id selector (`#reqDet`) instead of the class selector `.reqDet`.

Also, apart from that, you can make some improvements to your code:

1. Make your selector more explicit so that it doesn't have to examine *every* element in the page
2. Take advantage of `this` inside your callback so that you don't have to walk the DOM again
3. Use [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of `hide` and `show`, enabling you to lose the `if`

So you can reduce it to this:

```
$("select[title='requestType']").change(function(){ 
   $(".reqDet").toggle($(this).val() == ""); 
});
```

Comment: I've found that toggle is not working as there are four options for request type, and three of the four should be showing the .reqDet pane.

Comment: @jg100309: `toggle` will work just fine if you adjust the expression inside the parens. But it's really hard to help if you don't post *specific* information as part of the question.

Comment: I've got     $("select[title='requestType']").change(function(){ $(.reqDet").toggle($(this).val()!== ""); //if ($(this).val()!== "") { // $(.reqDet").show(); //} else { // $(.reqDet").hide(); //}); });

Comment: $("select[title='requestType']").change(function(){
    $(.reqDet").toggle($(this).val()!== "");

Comment: @jg100309: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) instead of posting comments, code in comments is impossible to make sense of.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    var details = $('tr#reqDet');
    var dropdown = $("select[title='requestType']");
    details.hide();

    dropdown.change(function() {
        details.toggle(dropdown.val() === '');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it intentional that you are hiding tr's with classname reqDet before you add the listener for the change event and then later try to hide an element with an id of reqDet? Also you should to specify what type of element has a title of request type:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr.reqDet").hide(); 

  $("select[title='requestType']").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val()!=""){
        $(".reqDet").hide();// should this be a class or id of reqDet 
    } else {  
        $(".reqDet").show();  // Change to "." to select class. # is selecting id so it isn't finding it. 
    }
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Yes, details row is to be hidden before user enters a request type. Four options, three of the choices should show the .reqDetails

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr.reqDet").hide(); 

  $("select[title='requestType']").change(function(){
    if ($("[title='requestType']").val()!=""){
        $("#reqDet").hide();
    } else {  
        $("#reqDet").show();  
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the if statement is working fine but the selector inside it is wrong. As you have mentioned the control which you want to show/hide has class `reqDet`, use the class selector. Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("tr.reqDet").hide(); 

   $("[title='requestType']").change(function(){
      if ($(this).val()){
          $(".reqDet").hide();
      } else {  
          $(".reqDet").show();  
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: @jg100309 - The issue is with `#reqDet` selector which you are using to show/hide the selector. You should use `.reqDet` since it is the class applied on the control which you are trying the show/hide.